# Metamask does not open on opera using web3modal

Tags: web3js, metamask, ethereum-wallet-dapp, react, web3-providers

I am using web3modal to connect with different wallets. On Mozilla I am able to connect with metamask but when I open my website on `Opera GX browser (version: LVL4 (core: 89.0.4447.64))` it says that `error: No CLV Wallet found`. Kindly let me know how I can fix this.

Thanks

Comment: I am having the same error. I am following the official `web3modal` docs listed [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/web3modal). As I understood it, Clover Wallet (or CLV Wallet) is another wallet and the `window.clover` is injected only if it is installed (just like `window.metamask`). But its absence shouldn't generate such errors.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to fix it is to use a newer (or the most recent) web3modal version. There was a known bug inside of web3modal. If you hadn't customized the options (in the code), the possibilities presented for Opera browsers by default were set up incorrectly, with the Clover wallet as a Web3 option and no Opera or MetaMask options.

You should check if the newest web3modal solves your problem:
https://web3modal.com/try-it-out