# On using Web3Modal to connect the metamask it shows error: " Error: No CLV Wallet found" on Opera GX Browser

Tags: solidity, ethers.js

[image]

But it works fine in Brave and Chrome.
If anyone faces this problem use other browsers.

Comment: Please, provide a minimal example that reproduces the error. The screen capture doesn't show relevant information. Did you try reporting in web3model github? perhaps it isn't compatible with opera gx.

Comment: Probably a duplicate of [this](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/133140/metamask-does-not-open-on-opera-using-web3modal)

Answer (score 0):

This problem is not a problem of Opera browser but instead in web3modal itself.

You are using a deprecated version of web3modal, which uses the Clover wallet as a default Web3 option, or you didn't add Opera as a custom provider.

Hint: I believe the newest version of web3modal supports Opera Wallet and MetaMask by default, so you might want to try it instead. https://web3modal.com/try-it-out